# Using the Material UI DatePicker with yup and react-hook-form - the error prop doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I'm working on a registration form made with yup, react-hook-form and Material UI DatePicker/TextField. I'd like to have a date of birth field that checks if the user is above 18 years old. The error message is displayed correcly but the red color of the error state works only if the input is empty (and not when the age is below 18). I'm console logging the value of "invalid" that dictates the red color, and it is set to true when it should.

Here is a sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/datepicker-yup-validation-8rod3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: your sandbox is empty

Comment: @SaeedShamloo Dunno how that happened, sorry. It's back up now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to just put `error` attribute after `{...params}` like this:

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      helperText={invalid ? error.message : null}
      id="dateOfBirth"
      variant="standard"
      margin="dense"
      fullWidth
      color="primary"
      autoComplete="bday"
      {...params}
      error={invalid}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Oh wow, it was that simple. Thank you, you're my savior. I've spent like a day on it <3

Comment: @WoXuS I'm having an issue with the onChange attribute. What you guys are using?

Comment: @fredyjimenezrendon you can see my code on CodeSandbox in the main post. What's your issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using DatePicker V6, these solutions do not currently work. In the new version, renderInput has been replaced by slotProps. Please check the code of [the link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76085161/6670104)