# unable to show error and error message on Material UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm using react Material UI

I want to show an error on some condition that will calculate on the backend.

I used Material UI-datepicker but I can't show error

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker';

const PickupDatePickerComponent = (props) => {

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  const handleChange = (newValue)=>{
    setValue(newValue);
  }

  const todayDate = new Date();

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider style={{ width:"100%"}} dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        label="example"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        minDate={todayDate}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField 
          error
          helperText="Your error message" 
          {...params} sx={{ width:"100%" }} 
        />}
        onError={true}
        error
        helperText="Your error message"
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export default PickupDatePickerComponent
```

the `error` property is not working not in `<Input/>` nor in `<DatePicker/>` so the border won't be red... (like normal errors)

Answer (score 30):

Put **error** attribute after
{...params} sx={{ width:"100%" }}
like this

```
renderInput={(params) => <TextField 
      
      {...params} sx={{ width:"100%" }} 
      error
      helperText="Your error message" 
    />}
```

Comment: How can you be such a genius? Thanks

Comment: Seriously, how on earth did you know that. Just saved hours and hours of wasted time. This is THE most useful post related to errors not displaying in MUI.

Comment: I believe this is a general javascript thing: when you use  the spread operator "...foo", you overwrite all the fields that were there before.  So that's why the order matters.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using DatePicker V6, these solutions do not currently work. In the new version, renderInput has been replaced by slotProps. Please check the code below.

**Code:**

```
<Controller
  name={name}
  control={control}
  render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
        {...field}
        label={label}
        slotProps={{
          textField: {
            fullWidth: fullWidth,
            variant: 'outlined',
            error: !!error,
            helperText: error?.message,
          },
        }}
        {...other}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )}
/>;
```

If you want more details about this update, please check [this link](https://mui.com/x/migration/migration-pickers-v5/#input-renderer-required-in-v5) on the official site.

Answer (score 4):

i passed to onError prop a callback function as recommended in [docs](https://next.material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/forms) , this is a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-ptolemy-e3mnbo?file=/src/App.js) based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find what `Controller` is in @Necip Sunmaz's comment, so I just created a state.

```js
const [dateError, setDateError] = useState(undefined);

<DateTimePicker
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      error: !!dateError,
      helperText: dateError,
    },
  }}
  onError={(err) => setDateError(err)}
  minDateTime={filter.date.startDate} // some other date state to cause the error
/>
```

Comment: [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/) is one of the main components of react-hook-form

Answer (score 0):

In the latest MUI (V6) DatePicker, the `renderInput` has been replaced with `slotProps`, in which case the same solution (i.e. `renderInput`...) would look like this:

```
<DatePicker ...
           slotProps={{
             textField: {
               helperText: isError?"Some error message":""
               error: isError,
             },
           }}
...  />
```